# Не работает Maven

Tags: java, windows-7, maven

При вводе в командной строке "mvn -version" получаю следующее сообщение

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(
>   SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadCl
>   ass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm
>   .java:247)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm
>   .java:239)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launch
>   er.java:144)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
>   cher.java:266)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
>   a:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
>   uncher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
>   356)

скачивал maven 3.2.5.
переменные окружения настроены верно.

Comment: @Sergey Isterin Докачивал maven-embedder, но не помогло

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте, что папка /lib в каталоге мавена не пуста. Симптомы сильно похожи на то, что описано тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889445/maven-mvn-version-java-lang-classnotfoundexception

Comment: По вашей ссылке читал ещё до того как писать сюда, папка не пустая. Даже перекачивал специально.

Comment: Тогда проверяем установку переменных окружения - M2_HOME должна смотреть в директорию установки мавена, например C:\Program Files\maven\. В Path необходимо добавить ссылку на /bin, как-нибудь так  %M2_HOME%\bin. В принципе это все действия, которые нужно совершить что бы мавен заработал. В качестве бонуса могу предложить проверить, что сама java установлена корректно и нужных версий.

Answer (score 0):

У меня был косяк в переменных, либо %M2_HOME% не отрабатывает, либо, в случае, если у вас установлены две версии maven, лучше просто в path прописать полный путь, например C:\Program Files\maven\bin;